# Export notebook to pdf in landscape orientation

Tags: export, pdf-format, cells

Assuming the following is a notebook with a linebreak:

[image]

How might I export a landscape pdf (preferred although other formats could work) such that **<s>each cell content</s> each group of cells** above and below the page break are stretched to take up half of the landscape page.

[image]

The colors are simply there to act as placeholders.  I certainly could copy and paste such data into a word document, but ideally something like this could be automated.

Comment: I struggle to understand the main part of your question.  Do you want to stretch a single blue and a single gray cell to each take up half the page?  p.s. please see [(1135)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1135/121)

Comment: @Mr.Wizard That is correct.  I probably should have put some cell content in the different colored boxes to make the question more clear.  I am looking to stretch the cell content so each box takes up half of the page.  Thank you for the link that is exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard To further clarify(in addition I added this information to the question) the colored region are not intended to signify a signal cell, but instead multiple different cells but multiple cells separated by a page break.

Comment: I was working on a solution for single blue/gray cells.  Do you still want that or should I just scrap it?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard If you have a working set of code that is relevant,  a posting would be appreciated.  I don't mind adapting the question or workflow to possibly reach a solution.

Comment: I haven't figured out the page breaking yet.  FWIW I was just setting `CellSize` to be half the printed page based on `72 * {8.5, 5.5}`.  I don't know how to transfer this to groups.  Are you open to alternative approaches such as painting the page with your blue/gray fill regardless of what cells overlie it?

Comment: Hang on now, you just changed line-break to page-break.  If that's a page break how do you have both blue and gray on the same page?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes I apologize I have reverted that back to linebreak.  Technically the picture shows a pagebreak but I used linebreak in the question.  Linebreak works just fine although that isn't what the picture shows.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The `CellSize` is quiet helpful.  Ultimately the original intent was to use `PageBreak` as a way to specify when the cells should wrap onto the next section of signal page.  This would likely require some type of pre-processing.  Cell grouping I thought would be inappropriate for trying to get the separate the different pages.  As you probably noticed I used both linebreak and pagebreak in the original and the current form of the question.  What do you think would be make the question more possible to answer?  Again the question could be changed slightly if needed.

Comment: I don't know what will be needed to implement this.  I haven't tried to do this before and I can't recall an equivalent question.  You might be able to use the single-cell approach with Inline Cells inside it, but usability would be poor I think.  I asked if coloring the background (the "paper") regardless of overlying cells would be acceptable; I don't think you answered that.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Please correct me if I am misunderstanding.  You are suggesting to simply have the background divided with the two colors while have the cell content stretched across the entire page?  Although that satisfies the picture requirements I was trying to ask a question more about layouts, and displaying cells side by side(landscape).  The `CellSize` is getting closer to what is needed.  I am thinking of just tring to rasterize the different cell content and then displaying it in a Grid side by side.

Comment: Yes, I think you understood my suggestion. (I know it's not a great one.)  It just hit me that you apparently want side-by-side columns; I was thinking merely in terms of paper size/shape.  Unfortunately there not much support for that; see [(30440)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/30440/121) and the linked Stack Overflow question.  I hope that one of the more layout-experienced users will still be able to provide you with a usable solution.  I think it might help if you gave a more concrete example of your usage.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thank you.  Your input has been very helpful. With the link that you provided I am quit hopeful to try and convert between ems and pixels and ems and get the sizing to work out.  The whole `ImageSize` vs `FieldSize` vs `ItemSize` isn't ideal IMO.  It is like a balancing act trying to get everything to work together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an entirely different technique, but I felt that is worth posting.  Really this question is asking how to print a [booklet](http://libraryasp.tamu.edu/tds/int/Newsletters/Online_Newsletters/v18n2/Styles/main/Reader/BookletPrinting.png) of Mathematica cells.

Although you can split a page into 2 groups of landscapes cells, IMO the above solution isn't very practical.  The above solution doesn't take into account that you might have multiple pages of cells.

The best solution I have found requires that you first run the following code.

```
changeOptions[nb_] := SetOptions[nb,
   StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
      Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
      Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], 
       CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, ShowCellLabel -> False],
      Cell[StyleData["Input", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
       CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
       LinebreakAdjustments -> {0.85, 2, 10, 1, 1}],
      Cell[
       StyleData["Input", "PrintoutGray", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
       CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
       LinebreakAdjustments -> {0.85, 2, 10, 1, 1}],
      Cell[StyleData["Code", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
       CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Background -> GrayLevel[1]],
      Cell[StyleData["Text", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
       CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Background -> GrayLevel[1]],
      Cell[StyleData["Code", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
       CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Background -> GrayLevel[1]],
      Cell[StyleData["Input", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
       CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
       LinebreakAdjustments -> {0.85, 2, 10, 1, 1}],
      Cell[StyleData["Output", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
       CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]
      }, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"],
   PrintingOptions -> {
     "FirstPageHeader" -> True,
     "PrintingMargins" -> {{60, 5}, {10, 10}}
     },
   PrintingStartingPageNumber -> 1,
   PageHeaders -> {
     {Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Page"]}], "PageNumber"], None, None},
     {None, None, Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Page"]}], "PageNumber"]}
     },
   PageFooters -> {
     {None, None, None}, {None, None, None}
     }
   ];
```

Next export the Notebook as a pdf and open it in [Adobe Reader](http://get.adobe.com/reader/) or [Foxit Reader](http://www.foxitsoftware.com/Secure_PDF_Reader/).  You should then be able to print the cells as a booklet under options. This [question](https://superuser.com/questions/553302/is-it-possible-to-automate-bulk-pdf-printing-with-specific-settings-in-adobe-rea) discusses possible ways to automate printing out such a booklet.

Alternatively you can use [PDF Booklet Creator](http://opensource.marten.dk/sider/pdf-booklet-creator_67.aspx)([fineprint](http://fineprint.com/) costs $) to create an actual pdf.

Answer (score 4):

You have to remove(set to 0) the margins for `Printout` in the current Stlysheet.  I have the Stylesheet installed on my computer and will hopeful post a more portable(not requiring you to install a new stylsheet solution).  The [following is a png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nI43w.png) showing the final output.

```
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 StyleDefinitions -> Notebook[{
    Cell[StyleData[StyleDefinitions -> "Default.nb"]],
    Cell[StyleData[All, "Printout"], ShowCellLabel -> False],
    Cell[StyleData["Text", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
     CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Background -> GrayLevel[1]]
    Cell[StyleData["Input", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
     CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}},
     LinebreakAdjustments -> {0.85, 2, 10, 1, 1}],
    Cell[StyleData["Code", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
     CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, Background -> GrayLevel[1]],
    Cell[StyleData["Input", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
     CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}, 
     LinebreakAdjustments -> {0.85, 2, 10, 1, 1}],
    Cell[StyleData["Output", "Printout", StyleDefinitions -> None], 
     CellMargins -> {{0, 0}, {0, 0}}]

    }, StyleDefinitions -> "PrivateStylesheetFormatting.nb"]
 ]
SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], 
 PrintingOptions -> {"FirstPageHeader" -> True}]
SetOptions[
 EvaluationNotebook[],
 PrintingOptions -> {
   "PrintingMargins" -> {{5, 10}, {10, 10}},
   "PaperOrientation" -> "Landscape"
   },
 PrintingStartingPageNumber -> 1,
 PageHeaders -> {
   {Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Page"]}], "PageNumber"], None, 
    None}, {Cell[TextData[{CounterBox["Page"]}], "PageNumber"], None, 
    None}
   },
 PageFooters -> {
   {None, None, None}, {None, None, None}
   }
 ]
sideBySide[x_, y_, size_] := Replace[
  ToBoxes@Grid[{{
      Pane[
       Grid[{{1}}, Spacings -> 0, Alignment -> {Left, Top}], 
       ImageSize -> size
       ], Pane[
       Grid[{{2}}, Spacings -> 0, Alignment -> {Left, Top}], 
       ImageSize -> size]
      }}, Spacings -> 0, Alignment -> {Left, Top}
     ], {{{"1"}} -> Map[({#}) &, x], {{"2"}} -> 
    Map[({#}) &, y]}, Infinity];
PrintingStyleEnvironment /. 
 Options[EvaluationNotebook[], PrintingStyleEnvironment];
```

And the printing the function like so.

```
RawBoxes@sideBySide[
  {Cell["text 3", "Text"], Cell["text 3", "Text"]},
  {Cell["text 3", "Text"], Cell["text 3", "Text"]},540
  ]
```