# Option precedence for CellLabel

Tags: notebooks, options, cells

In Mathematica, when an option is specified multiple times with different values, the first one will take precedence. This works with `Cell` and `Background`:

```
CellPrint@Cell["asd", "Text", Background -> Red, Background -> Blue]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

However, with the `CellLabel` option, the last one seems to take precedence.  This is unique and unusual. Is this a bug, or intentional?  Is there any reason why it should be like this?  Are there other options with such behaviour?

```
CellPrint@Cell["asd", "Text", CellLabel -> "one", CellLabel -> "two"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Wanted to test this but coudln't because I usually hav switched off `CellLabels` but where to switch them on again? It used to be in the `Preferences` (like [so](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/1138/764)) but it is not anymore. Where has that menu gone?

Comment: @gwr I am not sure, but I would try Option Inspector, Global Preferences (dropdown at top left), then search for ShowCellLabel. If it's False, set it to True.  In 11.1, many options were removed from the Preferences GUI to simplify things. These are always retained in the Option Inspector, but may have a more technical name there.

Comment: Thanks: `SetOptions[EvaluationNotebook[], ShowCellLabel -> True]` there we go.

Comment: Couldn't it be related to whether `Association` is used to represent large chunks of options internally:  With `Options` usually a symbol is changed by a rule and therefore a later rule will not affect it anymore. With `Association` the last value given to a `Key` counts.

Comment: @gwr I don't think it is related to associations for two reasons: (1) It's the same in v9 (2) These options seem to be handled by the front end (not kernel), which probably doesn't know anything about associations.  At first, I suspected that the front end is different from the kernel in that it always preserves the last (not first) option. But that is not the case as demonstrated with the `Background` option in the post.